# Selling in the money option

Tags: options

If the market price of a stock is 30, can I sell a call option that is currently in the money such as a strike price of 29?

Comment: Yes, you can and the logic in doing so should depend on other aspects but if you are naked the call, it might not be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you have account approval  to sell options then you can sell any strike price that you want as long as you have sufficient margin to support the transaction.

Comment: **"any"** as in $7.77, $9.99, or $12.3456? Or some other "any"?  :)

Comment: @Chris W. Rea - I'm sorry but I don't understand your question if it's a serious one or get the humor if you're kidding.  Assuming the former, options with odd strike prices like  $7.77 or $9.99  but not $12.3456  occasionally arise from special dividends or M&A so yes, you could sell "any"  of them if you have the approval to sell options as well as the available margin in your account.

Comment: I was too terse. I was wondering if "any strike price that you want" was intended to be interpreted liberally, e.g, the call writer could choose his *own* strike price, or whether it needs to be listed already. I've written options but always assumed I needed to stick to what is already listed. i.e. somebody else has established the available strikes?

Comment: @Chris W. Rea -  Strike prices for exchange traded options (US) are set by the exchange. You can request additional strikes be added. If the request is reasonable, they'll be available to trade the next day. For example, a $13.50 strike exists for the next 2 weeks  but not for the 3rd week.  OTOH, if the stock is $75 and there are strikes from $50 to $100, they won't add a $150 strike for you.  You can create your own strikes and other option terms with OTC deals but those are for the big players and that  transaction requires that the Investment  Bank  finding an agreeable counter party.